# How versionnig an android application works?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android and I would like to know (and understand) in detail how upgrading an application works.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google have explained all that [right here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html) in the Developer Docs.